# How to mount a shared folder in Oracle VM

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, virtual-machine

I want to use the files put in my desktop through hdfs comand. I am not able connect to my windows machine.

I have oracle VM installed and I have shared one folder from my machine.But I am not able to mount that .

Please help me out.

Comment: Oracle is a database. You can't mount a shared folder.

Comment: Oracle Virtual Machine..